# Simplifying Expression for Potential Energy of a Uniform Rod Attached by a Light String to a Fixed Point

Tags: physics

I am self-studying through *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering* and have come to a bit of a roadblock in chapter nine, on normal modes.

As [pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T12St.png), the system is a uniform rod attached to a fixed point $P$ by way of a light string. The potential energy is given in the book as
\begin{align}
V &= Mlg\left[(1-\cos\theta_{1})+\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos\theta_{2})\right]\\
&\approx \frac{1}{4}Mlg\left(2\theta_{1}^{2}+\theta_{2}^{2}\right)
\end{align}

My trouble is in transforming the first equation into the second; I have tried multiplying and dividing by the term in brackets but that didn't help. and I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $$ 1- \cos \theta = 2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} = 2 \left( \frac{\theta}{2}  + O(\theta^2)\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\theta^2 + O(\theta^4) \textrm{ as } \theta \to 0 $$
So for small $\theta_1, \theta_2$
$$ (1-\cos \theta_1 ) + \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos \theta_2) \approx \frac{1}{2} \theta_1^2 + \frac{1}{4} \theta_2^2 $$

Comment: Thank you! Does that identity have a name (so I can reference it in the future?)

Comment: Taylor series expansion of $\sin \theta$.